# Is there a way to validate fields without form tag and forms.py?

Tags: jquery, python, html, ajax, django

As the title said,I've been figuring out how to put error messages per field on html with django, since we were taught to do ajax without the use of forms.py nor form tags. Is there a solution for this? Or am I required to create forms for each?
Example:

**edit account function html**

```
{% for user in users %} 
<!--start EDIT MODAL -->
<div id="editAcct-{{user.id}}" class="modal fade" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">


  {% csrf_token %}
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="form-horizontal form-label-left input_mask">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close" required><span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
          </button>
          <h3 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Edit {{ user.username }}</h3>
        </div>

              <input type="hidden" name="pkid" id="pkid" class="form-control" value="{{ user.id }}"> 
        <div class="modal-body">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" for="id-num">ID Number
            </label>
            <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
              <input type="number" name="id-num" id="id-num-{{ user.id }}" class="form-control" value="{{ user.profile.employeeID }}" required> 
            </div>

          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" for="first-name">First Name
            </label>
            <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
              <input type="text" id="first-name-{{ user.id }}" name="first-name" class="form-control" value="{{ user.first_name }}" required>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" for="last-name">Last Name
            </label>
            <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
              <input type="text" id="last-name-{{ user.id }}" name="last-name" class="form-control" value="{{ user.last_name }}" required>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" for="user-name">Username
            </label>
            <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
              <input type="text" id="user-name-{{ user.id }}" name="user-name" class="form-control" value="{{ user.username }}" required>
            </div>



          </div>



          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="middle-name" class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">Email</label>
            <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
              <input id="email-{{ user.id }}" class="form-control" type="email" name="email" value="{{ user.email }}" required>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
         <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          <button type="submit" onClick="editAcctAjax({{ user.id }})" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
{% endfor %}

<!-- end EDIT MODAL -->
```

**ajax javascript code**

```
<script>

    function editAcctAjax(id){
      var employeeid = document.getElementById('id-num-' + id).value;
      var firstname = document.getElementById('first-name-' + id).value;
      var lastname = document.getElementById('last-name-' + id).value;
      var username = document.getElementById('user-name-' + id).value;
      var email = document.getElementById('email-' + id).value;
        $.ajax({url: '/editModal/?pkid='+ id + '&id-num=' + employeeid + '&first-name=' + firstname + '&last-name=' + lastname + '&username=' + username + '&email=' + email, 
            success: function(data){
              window.location.reload();

              // $("#testRefresh").replaceWith($("#testRefresh",$(data)));
              // window.location.reload();

            },
             error: function(data) { 
                alert("invalid!");
            }    
            // error:function(data){
            //   alert("invalid!");
            // }
        });
    }
</script>
```

**views.py for edit account**

```
def editModal(request):

JSONer = {}
valid = True
parsedData = urlparse.urlparse(request.get_full_path())
pkid = (urlparse.parse_qs(parsedData.query)['pkid'][0])
idnum = (urlparse.parse_qs(parsedData.query)['id-num'][0])
firstname = (urlparse.parse_qs(parsedData.query)['first-name'][0])
lastname = (urlparse.parse_qs(parsedData.query)['last-name'][0])
username = (urlparse.parse_qs(parsedData.query)['username'][0])
email = (urlparse.parse_qs(parsedData.query)['email'][0])
error_msg1 = "empty"
error_msg2 = "empty"
context = {
'valid':valid,
'error_msg1':error_msg1,
'error_msg2':error_msg2,

}


if User.objects.filter(id=pkid).count() > 0:

    if Profile.objects.filter(Q(employeeID=idnum) & ~Q(user_id=pkid)).count() > 0:
        valid = False
        error_msg1 = "id is taken"
        print("id is already taken!")
    if User.objects.filter(Q(username = username) & ~Q(id=pkid)).count() > 0:
        valid = False
        error_msg2="username is taken"
        print("username is taken")
        messages.error(request,'Username is taken!',extra_tags="sameuser")
    if User.objects.filter(Q(email = email) & ~Q(id=pkid)).count() > 0:
        valid = False
        print("email is already taken!")
    if valid == False:
        response = HttpResponse(status=401)
        response['Content-Length'] = len(response.content)
        return response
    else:
        userID = User.objects.filter(id=pkid)[0]
        userID.profile.employeeID = idnum
        userID.first_name = firstname
        userID.last_name = lastname
        userID.username = username
        userID.email = email
        userID.save()
        messages.success(request,"Successfully updated account!")
    return HttpResponse(json.dumps(JSONer),context)


return HttpResponse(json.dumps(JSONer),context)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can still use form class to validate only in backend

views.py

```
def editModal(request):
    form = UserForm(request)
    if form.is_valid():
        # Do something
    else:
        # Do something else
```

Use form class to write validation rules
    https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/forms/validation/